# SQL Syntax error on table update

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error, sql-update

Why is that I'm getting a syntax error on the following SQL statement under sqlite?

Error reads:

> SQL Error: near "SET": syntax error

```
UPDATE nova
       SET Nome = (select Nome from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID),
       SET Morada = (select Morada from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID),
       SET Email = (select Email from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID),
       SET TelfCasa = (select TelfCasa from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID),
       SET TelfEmprego = (select TelfEmprego from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID),
       SET Telemovel = (select Telemovel from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID),
       SET Fax = (select Fax from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (select * from assessores where nova.ID = assessores.ID);
```

If I try to fully qualify the SET field names, the error becomes:

> SQL Error: near ".": syntax error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need one `SET` at the beginning. You can also simplify the query by joining the two tables together and eliminating the sub-queries.

```
UPDATE nova JOIN assessores ON nova.ID = assessores.ID
SET nova.Nome        = assessores.Nome,
    nova.Morada      = assessores.Morada,
    nova.Email       = assessores.Email,
    nova.TelfCasa    = assessores.TelfCasa,
    nova.TelfEmprego = assessores.TelfEmprego,
    nova.Telemovel   = assessores.Telemovel,
    nova.Fax         = assessores.Fax;
```

Comment: You're right about the usage of `SET` but I don't think SQLite supports multi-table `UPDATE` syntax.  You're showing MySQL syntax.

Comment: It does support it. That was not the problem. It's been a while since I last used SQL and while looking at the syntax on SQLite documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) was completely missing the fact SET was not part of the field=value cycle.